# Kitchen Wall Type

Tags: kitchens

[image]I own a home that was built in 1959. I am getting ready to start a full remodel on the kitchen. I plan on widening the door way..etc... I cut out a small test area of the wall,and the material was 1" thick. I am almost positive it is not drywall. Any idea what material it might be?

Comment: What is the material on the underside?  Can't tell from the picture if it is a heavy paper or wood slat.

Comment: Its a brown paper..this piece was nailed to a stud

Answer (score 2):

Most likely [lath and plaster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lath_and_plaster).

Answer (score 2):

All the homes built after the war were either plaster and lath or gypsum plaster boards. They were like 48 x 16 and were applied like drywall boards then skim coated over the top. Be careful though: sometimes the compound contained asbestos.

Comment: Sometimes (as in our 1948 house), the skim coat is multilayered.  We've got gypsum plaster boards + about 1 inch of a coarse cement-like substance + skim coat of finish plaster.  The middle cement-like layer also has a ton of what looks like horse hair in it.   The OP's wall reminds me of ours.